# Pivot Table does not refresh using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, pivot, refresh

I have a pivot created in excel 365

My sourcedata is in a Ms Access Query

I built a macro in Excel to refresh the pivot but I got an error message.

```
Runtime error 1004

Unable to get PivotTables property of the worksheet class
```

The code I wrote:

```
Sub Refresh_Pivot01()
'
' Refresh_Pivot01 Macro
'
Sheets("PivotData").Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh*

End Sub
```

The code `ThisWorkbook.RefreshAll` does only work if the sourcedata is in the same excelsheet and in my case the sourcedata is in a MS Access Query

There must be something wrong but I can not figure it out !
Can someone help me out here ??

Answer (score 0):

No need to select stuff ([read here why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba))

Fully qualify your objects.

See how I set a reference to the `workbook`, `sheet` and `pivot table` by using their pointers

Replace the `TheWorkbookName` with the actual workbook name

```
Public Sub RefreshPivotTable()
    
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks("TheWorkbookName")
    
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("PivotData")
    
    targetSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub
```

Let me know if it works

Comment: Hi Richard, thanks for your quick reply; I copied your line of coding but got the same errormessage; Public Sub RefreshPivotTable()
    
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks("Cemis-Recharge_02.xlsm")
    
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("PivotData")
    
    targetSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

End Sub

Comment: If you press `F8`key to debug the code, what line rises the error?

Comment: Application defined or object defined error

Comment: That's the error. But what line in the code is raising it?

Comment: If I change the coding to "Pivottable2" I get another errormessage:  Method Pivottables or object Worksheet failed

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention the error occurred on the last line: targetSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotCache.Refresh

Comment: You have to check what's the PivotTable Name [read this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/rename-a-pivottable-or-pivotchart-f8b73921-3494-48e2-a271-ce6c5d371cf4)

Comment: Hi Ricardo, In pivot table options I can see the name is PivotTable1 so that must be ok...

Comment: Got it. If you right click the pivot table and select refresh what happens?

Comment: Then I see 1 milli second on the left corner of my excelsheet that the backgroundquery is running and than the pivot refreshes. So manually it does refresh

Comment: The strange thing is that in some excelsheets (all xlsm format) it works (other query in Ms Access but same database) but in some it does not !!

Comment: So the problem is not the procedure. You’ll have to check the source data and the way the pivot table is linked